# Spring radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I am totally new to Spring and have posted this question in another forum, there is no reply yet, so I am posting it here as well. I have the following doubt:

```
<form:radiobuttons id="..." path="..." items= "${stuff}" cssStyle="..."></form:radiobuttons>  
<form:radiobuttons id="..." path="..." items= "${stuff}" cssStyle="..."></form:radiobuttons>
```

For the above radio button, what is this piece of code: 
items= "${stuff}"
doing? Hope someone can advise. Thanks.

regards

Answer (score 0):

In SpringMVC controller,You can new a Model and model.addAttribute("stuff",value),then "${stuff}" will be the value.I am new to SpringMVC too.This is what i know.

Comment: value as in, the option clicked by the user?

Comment: yes.readr this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-radiobutton-and-radiobuttons-example/)